# Google Sheets: leaving a cell value unchanged If importhtml returns a #N/A error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a custom function to prevent the value of a cell from changing if the importhtml returns a #n/a error.

This formula summarize the idea: `=IF(ISNA(IMPORTHTML("http://www.example.com","table",1)), "do not change cell value", IMPORTHTML("http://www.example.com","table",1))`

I thought about saving the cell value before executing the importhtml function, so I could put the saved value back if the importhtml returns a #n/a error.

I've been testing a lot of different codes, but always got some error as a result.

I will be very grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: Now my current script is the suggested by @ziganotschka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a secondary sheet
- Copy-paste once values only from the primary sheet with the `importhtml` formula to the secondary sheet
- Write a script that will  copy all the values from the primary to the secondary sheet that are [not NaN](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan_number.asp)
- Bind to the script an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) onChange trigger that will run the script each time an update of `IMPORTHTML` takes place

### Sample script:

```
function onChange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var importSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var finalSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var importRange=importSheet.getDataRange();
  var data=importRange.getValues();
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j<data[0].length;j++){
      if(!isNaN(data[i][j])){
        finalSheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).setValue(data[i][j]);
    }
  }
 }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It's working great! (except for googlefinance formulas because of [google restrictions](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/09/historical-googlefinance-data-no-longer.html).